# Ubuntu script to rename every file in folders and sub directories NOT matching sha1sum

Tags: bash

On Ubuntu i have run this command.

```
 sha1sum /home/abcd/random/1/1.mp4
```

So I have the following directory

```
/home/abcd/
```

Inside this folder are sub folders

```
/home/abcd/1
/home/abcd/2
etc
etc
```

These sub folders are filled with video files `.mp4` extensions

They have multiple files with a file hash of `sha1sum` of `3c72363260a32992c3ab2e3a5e9b8cf082e02eac` i wanted to **rename all the files NOT matching this file to**

```
vid_1.mp4
vid_2.mp4
etc
etc
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to hash all `*.mp4`'s or It has been hashed already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `for` loop with a nested `if` loop

```
for f in /home/abcd/*; do
    i=$((i+1));
    sum=$(sha1sum "$f" | awk '{print $1}');
    if [[ "$sum" != 3c72363260a32992c3ab2e3a5e9b8cf082e02eac ]]; then
        mv "$f" "vid_$i.mp4"; 
    fi; 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

pseudocode

- find mp4s
- sha1sum them (outputs `<sha1sum> <filename>`)
- pass lines not `3c72363260a32992c3ab2e3a5e9b8cf082e02eac`
- change lines from `<sha1sum> <filename>` to `mv "<filename>" "vid_<filename"`
- execute the lines

code

```
cd /home/abcd
find . -name "*.mp4" -print0 |
  xargs -r -0 sha1sum |
  awk '$1!="3c72363260a32992c3ab2e3a5e9b8cf082e02eac"' |
  sed 's/^[^\s]\+\s\+\(.*\)/mv "\1" "vid_\1"/' |
  sh
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I got this error. sh
sh: 11: bdb28d06836c3941a06966a9f55d8646de83e97e: not found
sh: 12: 665304360a207714032e829c806b2db689bc5be3: not found
sh: 17: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: The filename is not 3c72363260a32992c3ab2e3a5e9b8cf082e02eac but that is the files hash sum itself i just wanted to rename all files not matching that files hash sum.

Comment: @C0nw0nk : Don't post this problem in a comment, but write a question, where we can see what command is actually executed. Also, run your script with `-x`, for better debugging.

Comment: apologies for the typo; fixed now.